# How to create a dask-array from CuPy array?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, cupy, dask-ml

I'm trying to launch `dask.cluster.Kmeans` with the huge amount of data.
Working with CPU is OK since i wrap `numpy` arrays with `dask.array`.
Working with GPU doesn't seem to be possible due to not implemented functionalities in `cupy`.

I've tried to reproduce Mattew Rocklin example (https://blog.dask.org/2019/01/03/dask-array-gpus-first-steps) on generating random dask array from CuPy random generator - and it works, but it's not the case I want to use.

Wrapping `cupy` with `dask.array` - doesn't work.

```
>>> import dask.array as da
>>> import cupy as cp
>>> da.from_array(cp.arange(100000)).sum().compute()
```

I expect the sum of this array but get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/cupy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 175, in compute
    (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/cupy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 446, in compute
    results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/cupy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/threaded.py", line 82, in get
    **kwargs
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/cupy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 491, in get_async
    raise_exception(exc, tb)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/cupy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/compatibility.py", line 130, in reraise
    raise exc
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/cupy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 233, in execute_task
    result = _execute_task(task, data)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/cupy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 119, in _execute_task
    return func(*args2)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/cupy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/array/core.py", line 100, in getter
    c = np.asarray(c)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/cupy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 538, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: object __array__ method not producing an array
```

So how could I manage the work with CuPy through the dask array?

Comment: What is your version of cupy?

Comment: @mdurant, versions of packages:
`cupy-6.0.0`, `dask-2.0.0`
Installed from `defaults`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating the Dask Array from a CuPy array, you need to supply `da.from_array` the keyword argument `asarray=False`. So your code would look like the following.

```py
>>> import dask.array as da
>>> import cupy as cp
>>> da.from_array(cp.arange(100000), asarray=False).sum().compute()
```

Comment: Thanks @akirkham, it works.
Unfortunately, not implemented CuPy features won't get me an opportunity to launch `dask_ml.cluster.KMeans` on `dask.array` of `cupy` objects.

Comment: Thanks for the info, @RostislavPovelikin.

If you know which functions are missing from CuPy, could you please raise some issues on that repo? We can follow up there.

Independently you may also consider trying `dask-cuml`, which also implements `KMeans`.